# How to create Alphanumeric Auto Increment

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone guide me or at least give me tutorial links I wanted to create an alphanumeric auto increment ID/Code with the following format 123-A00000010-A12 the 123 and A12 is constant and the A00000010 is auto increment.

Comment: sample data? what happens after 123-A99999999-A12? Oh yeah - what have **you tried**?

Comment: This site is for questions, it's not a free coding service.

Comment: Only your program will manage the ID generation?

Comment: B00000001 i think my db could not reach that far

Comment: @Blorgbeard im not asking for a code, i only ask for an idea or tutorial would be the best if theres any. I already have an idea but two heads is always better than one.

Comment: @Rodrigo yes. Iv tried random but i guess it would be better to increment. from 0 to millions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably some overkill for a simple task, but I felt like doing an exercise:

The ID class

```
public class AlphaNumericID
{
    private string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public int Alpha { get; protected set;}
    public int Numeric { get; protected set; }

    public int NumericLenght { get; protected set; }

    public string KeyFront { get; protected set; }
    public string KeyEnd { get; protected set; }

    public AlphaNumericID(string keyFront, string keyEnd, int numericLength)
    {
        Alpha = 0;
        Numeric = 1;

        KeyFront = keyFront;
        KeyEnd = keyEnd;

        NumericLenght = numericLength;
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        Numeric++;

        if (Numeric == Math.Pow(10, NumericLenght))
        {
            Alpha++;
            Numeric = 1;

            if (Alpha == chars.Length)
                throw new Exception("Overflow!");
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}-{1}{2}-{3}", KeyFront, chars[Alpha], Numeric.ToString().PadLeft(NumericLenght, '0'), KeyEnd);
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

- Declare

  ```
  var id = new AlphaNumericID("123", "A12", 8); //Will create 123-A00000001-A12
  ```

  (Although if you know your database will never go so high you may want to consider using a shorter id)
- Increment

  ```
  id.Increment();
  ```
- Output

  ```
  id.ToString();
  ```

The benefit of this encapsulation is that you can extend and change its inner implementation easily, although it might be way too large for your particular needs.

Comment: I thank you so much for giving me complete code.

Comment: you're welcome, but despite the code being readily usable, you still should look at the code itself and try to understand what is going on. This will help you learn and maybe you find ways of improving it yourself :)

Comment: Yes im doing it right now thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a simple counter to increment and a second property that takes that number and outputs a formatted string with your ID format.

You write something like this:

```
int Counter= 100; 
string ID=String.Format("123-A{0}-A12",Counter);
```

Comment: for 099 what did you used string.Replace from 099 to 100 ?

Comment: You dont replace. You have say  int Counter= 100;  and  string ID=String.Format("123-A{0}-A12",Counter);

Comment: And probably Counter.ToString("00000000") if you want your value to appear as 123-A00000010-A12 instead of 123-A10-A12

Answer (score 1):

You say something like this:

```
 private void bntOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int cnt10, ntEQ;
        cnt10 = 10;
        string id = null;  
        string dsp = txtInput.Text.Trim(' '); 

        int rs = string.Compare(dsp, "9");
        if (rs == 0)
        {
            id = string.Format("123-000000{00}-A12", cnt10);
            txtResult.Text = id; 
        }

        else 
        {
            int dspt = Convert.ToInt16(txtInput.Text.Trim());
            ntEQ = dspt + 1;
            id = string.Format("123-000000{00}-A12", ntEQ);
            txtResult.Text = id;
        }

    }
```