# Entity Framework auto increment unique alphanumeric code generating

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, fluent

I need to add an auto increment unique alphanumeric column(Code) to my all EF Code First classes. But, This column is not the Id(Key).

Is there anyway for me to define the auto increment field in code, or would creating the column myself and defining in the DB that its auto increment work?

For Example :

```
public class Document{
[Key]
public int DocumentId { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; }

// This code should be auto generated whenever a record will be inserted For Example : DOC000001,DOC000002 and so on.
public string Code{ get; set; }

public DateTime LastModifiedDate{ get; set; }}
```

Comment: try using Guid instead of int

Comment: can I use Guid for my own custome Code generation ?

Comment: can't you combine a sequence with a calculated column ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built in Database function to do this ... unless you use a GUID(but that is not a auto increment). If this is something you truely want to do then you need to write your own method to do it

there are several answers on this site on how to do this in C# this is one example

[How to create Alphanumeric Auto Increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771678/how-to-create-alphanumeric-auto-increment)